# Entity framework core relationships - foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

Since I've just started learning entity framework I'm wondering how to properly create relationships between two tables.

I would try it myself but I can't even setup database connection :(

Here's my question, here are two classes (tables) `Student` and `Grade`:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{

    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }

}
```

As in example above I realized that adding type `Grade` as property would create relation to table `Grade`,
**NOW IMPORTANT THING** but what about `GradeId` which obliviously hold foreign key value? It's located above `Grade` type and it's name is `GradeId`, what if I located it somewhere else and named it like `StudentGradeId`, would that still be the `ForeignKeyId`? or it has to be stricly (contains type + Id together like in my example) : `TypeNameId = GradeId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF will match up Navigation Properties to Foreign Key Properties by convention.  So if your Navigation Property is called Grade and the Foreign Key property is called GradeId, they will be automatically matched.

If they don't follow the convention, you just have to explicitly configure them by decorating the properties with a [ForeignKeyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute?view=netframework-4.8), or by using the Fluent API in [OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Comment: so if my property is called Grade and Foreign Key prop is called StudentGradeId, than Im not following convention? Thankks